# Camel Pretty Print

Tags: java, apache-camel, pretty-print

Can you please help me figure out how to keep the original file name with my custom processor? I implemented a prettyPrint processor for handling generic xml files. It works except the file name changes to a camel generated file name. I haven't been able to figure out how to maintain the original file name.
This is my route:

```
from("file:{{xslt_out_Event}}?delete=true")
    .log("Getting file ${file:name}")
    .process(prettyPrintprocessor)
    .to("file:{{etl_ready_Event}}");
```

and this is my processor:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
    String fileContents=FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    //String = fileName=exchange.getIn().getHeader("org.apache.camel.file.name").toString();
    String fileName=file.getName();
    logger.debug("fileName="+fileName);
    String prettyContents=XMLUtil.formatXml(fileContents);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(prettyContents, String.class);
    //exchange.getOut().setHeader("org.apache.camel.file.name", fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though pvpkiran's answer is technically correct I'd say that the simplest solution would be to just reuse the `In` part of the exchange rather than creating a new `Out` part.

When you do this:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(prettyContents, String.class);
```

you're creating a new `Message` without any of the headers from the original message. So by instead doing this:

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(prettyContents, String.class);
```

you'll simply replace the old file contents with the new while keeping the `CamelFileName` header intact (as well as any other headers). Now when you write the file to your output directory the file name will remain unchanged.

[Here](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) you can read more about how and when to use `getIn` and `getOut` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelFileName", ${header.CamelFileName}
```

Add this in your processor.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
    String fileContents=FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    //String = fileName=exchange.getIn().getHeader("org.apache.camel.file.name").toString();
    String fileName=file.getName();
    logger.debug("fileName="+fileName);
    String prettyContents=XMLUtil.formatXml(fileContents);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(prettyContents, String.class);
    exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelFileName", ${header.CamelFileName} );
}
```